# How to index for values that are not in another table

Tags: sql, sqlite, query-performance

I need to find all the IDs that are in one table but not in another.

The simple select I have is:

```
SELECT ID 
FROM  Table1 
WHERE ID NOT IN (SELECT id FROM Table2)
```

But if I do an `EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN` I get

```
"0"|"0"|"0"|"SCAN TABLE Table1"
"0"|"0"|"0"|"USING INDEX index_Table2_id FOR IN-OPERATOR"
```

Both my tables have `id` defined as `id integer PRIMARY KEY`, (for `table1`) and a normal index for `table2`.

Any suggestion on how I could speed up that query?

I have ~200000 records in `table1` and ~2 Million records in `table2`, the query takes around 500ms to run.

What could be causing the query to run so slowly, any suggestions on  how I could speed it up?

Comment: 500 milliseconds to compare the entirety of two tables seems fast to me.

Comment: You are scanning both tables with large amount of data. And as Gordon pointed out 500ms is fast enough for such query.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `LEFT JOIN` together with a `WHERE` clause of `table2.ID IS NULL`:

```
SELECT table1.ID
FROM table1 LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.ID = table2.ID
WHERE table2.ID IS NULL;
```

I believe this is faster.